# Online C++ compiler where I could disable copy-elision

Tags: c++

I would like to know of an online browser where I could test some C++ code **and also have the option of disabling copy-elision and optimization**. The purpose of this is to test some of my C++ concepts.

Comment: [Stacked Crooked](http://stacked-crooked.com) and [GCC Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/)

Comment: Thanks I remember there was a parameter for disabling copy-elision also. Could you tell me what that was ?

Comment: You can configure options for both copy-elision and optimization using the compiler option `-fnoelid_constructors` and the `-0n` option respectively.

Comment: @0x499602D2 thanks could you put that down as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two good ones I know of:

- [Stacked Crooked](http://stacked-crooked.com/)
- [GCC Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/)

The options for handling copy-elision and optimization would be `-fno-elide-constructors` and `-0n` respectively.

Comment: -fno-elide-constructors` is correct.